# Fill missing dates with another column value

Tags: python, pandas, date

I've been trying to do something that I thought would be simple, but I'm facing an issue I'm not understanding. I have two columns: `date_published` and `date_obtained`, of course, I've got all data for `date_obtained`, but not for `date_published`. My approach was to fill the missing `date_published` with date obtained minus 1 day (might also be the median difference, but I'll ignore that).

df looks like this:

```
date_published    date_obtained
 2017-12-20        2017-12-22
    NaT            2017-12-23
```

And should look like this afterwards:

```
date_published    date_obtained
 2017-12-20        2017-12-22
 2017-12-22        2017-12-23
```

I tried the following:

```
date_delta=(Df.date_obtained-datetime.timedelta(days=1))
Df.loc['date_published']=Df.date_published.fillna((date_delta))
```

But, to my surprise, that didn't fill any `NaT`, and also created a missing value in all of my data frame. Also tried filling with just `Df.date_obtained` , but the result was the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Does `df['date_published'] = df.date_published.fillna(df.date_obtained - pd.Timedelta(days=1))` work?

Comment: It did indeed work! Could you care to explain what is the difference to Python between both syntaxes? I had a similar code that used a mask to replace on some that, and thus needed to use `.loc` , so I guessed it would be needed here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you should've either done:

```
u = df.date_obtained - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
df['date_published'] = df.date_published.fillna(u)
```

Or,

```
df.loc[:, 'date_published'] = df.date_published.fillna(u)
```

Using `loc` to refer to the columns (otherwise, it will try to check the index for the label you passed).